# Regroup Java classes by packages in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package, hierarchy

I have a large number of Java projects in Eclipse, all containing source code with common package hierarchy. Only the last subpackages differ.

It is a real pain to navigate through the projects to look for a file or another when you want to have a clear view of the package architecture. Thus, is there a way to display all classes of a group of projects in a common package hierarchy?

Comment: Nobody answered precisely my question yet...

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a way to accomplish that in Eclipse currently as this is a very rare scenario. However, you can abbreviate the package names by going to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance, and checking the Abbreviate package names option. This will allow you to define rules like this:

```
com.example.application.foo.bar=(foobar)
```

and a **com.example.application.foo.bar.package.subpackage** will appear as **(foobar).subpackage**. This will reduce the clutter in your worspace a little bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, at least I will have learnt something :) However i do not think this is a very rare scenario. A lot of maven projects seem to be distributed in several directories that make up for several projects or root source directories, while it is interesting to see the project's package hierarchy as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

You could define a working set of projects your interested in. In the package explorer, you can select those working sets as top level elements. Also, when doing a shift-ctrl-t, you can restrict your search to a working set.

Comment: This is not an answer to my problem :( I don't want to group projects together, i want to group all classes from all projects together into a common package view.